# Алгоритм поиска фальшивой монеты

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, c++

Сама задача такова:

Имеется 3n монет, среди которых есть фальшивая (тяжелее всех остальных). Требуется с помощью чашечных весов без гирь ровно на n взвешиваний определить номер фальшивой монеты. 
Пользователь вводит 0, если весы уравновешены.

1. Если перевесила левая чаша.
2. Если перевесила правая чаша.

После каждого ввода 0, 1 или 2 выводит новые интервалы массива. Не знаю как организовать функцию, чтоб она делила массив на 3 части.

```
for (int i = 0; i <=1*p/3; i++) 
{
    arr1[i]=arr[i];
}
for (int i = 1*p/3; i <=2*p/3; i++) 
{
    arr2[i]=arr[i];
}
for (int i = 2*p/3; i <=p; i++) 
{
    arr3[i]=arr[i];
}
```

Comment: не можете организовать ввод 0,1 или 2?

копирование массива обычно делают так

    #include <algorithm>
    //....
    int a_len = p/3;
    std::copy(arr, arr+a_len, arr1);
    std::copy(arr+a_len, arr+a_len*2, arr2);
    std::copy(arr+a_len*2, arr+a_len*3, arr3);

красивее и проще. 

да и на `std::vector` лучше заменить.

Comment: А нужно ли копирование массива? Более того, нужен ли вообще массив? Подсказка: массив предназначен для хранения значений. Но значений у нас нет, у нас есть только интервалы, которые в процессе сходятся к единственному индексу.